# Why floated buttons cant keep their position?

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

In snippet you can see, that if i want to past floated button/group they cant keep position in relative segment. Whats wrong with my layout?
Code listing u can see  https://codepen.io/saveurmind/pen/oWXWOa
Content of header placed in segment, I'm using full size column(16) in raw.
If i use buttons without "right floated" - all is ok. 
[image]

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="sixteen wide column"> 
    <div class="header-bar">
    <div class="ui segment">
     <div class="header-content">
      <h3 class="ui header">Title</h3>
      <div class="ui right floated basic buttons">
       <div class="ui button">One</div>
       <div class="ui button">Two</div>
       <div class="ui button">Three</div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use clearfix to contain your child element in your parent block.

```
.clearfix:after {
   content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
```

If you want title with same line as btn, two way to go:

1. change h3 to span (cus h1~h6 will take the whole line)

https://codepen.io/hdl881127/pen/bWdRVp

2. if you want keep h3, then you need to add a new class called

https://codepen.io/hdl881127/pen/BRNZLj

```
.inlineblock{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

More info about clearfix you can read it here:

[What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix)

Comment: but in this case buttons not on the same line as "Title"

Comment: @SomeBerry you want same line? ok wait a sec

Comment: @SomeBerry check my update answer, two way to make them same line

Comment: You are the best! Thank you :)

Comment: May i ask one more question? what if i want "tittle" to be vertical-align: middle? Nothing happens when i try to use it. Without it text on top of block

Comment: @SomeBerry something like this? https://codepen.io/hdl881127/pen/wdaemg

Comment: no, not "center". i mean that i need left-aligned text, but on middle of block. as example - on one line as text in buttons.

Comment: @SomeBerry something like this? https://codepen.io/hdl881127/pen/OmVjBE

Comment: Yeeah! Great thnx!